# How to broadcast messages among processes in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am creating a list of nodes in Python and I wish they can broadcast messages among themselves.

The current code is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
NUM_PROC = 10
import time


class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, node_id):
        self.id = node_id
        self.neighbours = []

    def talk_to_neighbours(self):
        for n in self.neighbours:
            print "Hi Node " + str(n.id) + ", this is greeting from Node " + str(self.id)
            time.sleep(1)

def wrapper_func(node):
    return node.talk_to_neighbours()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    node_list = [Node(i) for i in range(10)]

    for node in node_list:
        node.neighbours = [neighbour_node for neighbour_node in node_list if neighbour_node.id != node.id]

    pool = mp.Pool(NUM_PROC)
    pool.map(wrapper_func, node_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

where there is no IPC at all.

The basic utilities `Queues` and `Pipes` of the `multiprocessing` module doesn't look like natively supporting broadcast.
What I can think of is to connect each pair of nodes manually and then use `Queues` and `Pipes`.
I am wondering if there are any simpler solutions since this one is tedious.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? From your code, I would assume some version of Python 2, but if you're open to v3.4+, you could use `asyncio` to make those tasks asynchronous.

Comment: @ZachGates, I am using Python 2

Comment: In Python 2, that's probably the most straightforward way you could accomplish it.